# How does Postgres perform an inner join query and what information is required to optimize it?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a relatively simple inner join query which I am running on a SQL database - Postgres to be precise.

The exact query is shown below. It is a simple `inner join` query between two tables with a simple `table1.id == table2.id` type condition, followed by a `select` to extract a subset of the available column data.

```
explain select ps.property_id, location_id
    from property_static ps inner join property_location pl
        on ps.property_id = pl.property_id
            order by ps.property_id asc;
```

It doesn't matter too much exactly what these things are. The two tables contain data about properties (houses) and locations (geographical regions).

The output from this explain statement is as follows:

```
Merge Join  (cost=9.23..261420.13 rows=3382911 width=16)
  Merge Cond: (ps.property_id = pl.property_id)
  ->  Index Only Scan using property_static_pkey on property_static ps  (cost=0.42..80015.42 rows=620092 width=8)
  ->  Index Only Scan using ix_property_location_property_id_location_id on property_location pl  (cost=0.43..137599.00 rows=3382911 width=16)
JIT:
  Functions: 3
  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
```

It looks to be as simple as two full table scans to read the data and then some other operation to aggregate it.

Since I have already defined two indexes on the condition columns, the full table scan is already optimized using an index scan.

Is this enough to optimize this particular type of query?

Part of the reason for asking is that I don't know how an `inner join` query is performed internally by Postgres. Select queries with conditions are realtively transparent, and to find the data efficiently it is relatively obvious that an index should be defined which is composed of the columns used in the condition.

Comment: Perhaps [this article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/join-strategies-and-performance-in-postgresql/) can help you to understand the join strategies.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe so this looks like a so called "merge join" which requires sorting on the condition columns first. Since an index is typically a btree (it is in this case) I would assume this essentially means the sorted order is known and therefore the sort operation is just a noop?

Comment: It is definitely not a no-operation, since it requires reading the entire index and fetching the table rows in that order (which is expensive). But it is cheaper than a sort, so PostgreSQL goes for it.

Comment: "...It looks to be as simple as two full table scans..." -- well, yes. Your query does not have any filtering predicate. This shouldn't be a surprise.